# Laravel to new server, all styles broken (but there is no 404 error)

Tags: laravel

I recently migrated a laravel application from an add-on domain server to its own dedicated server. However, the site is now showing with plain text, with no css and no js. When I inspected the site, there is no 404 error but instead there are bunch of java errors (like $ is not found)

I have tried the below
1) edited the document root from public_html to public_html/public (which worked in the add on domain server)
2) edited the .htaccess
3) edited the App/AppServiceProvider registration method 
4) edited the index.php

url is http://85.187.132.48

Here is my .htaccess in root and public

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

I expect the site is running properly.

Comment: You'll first need to change the database name and user to match with the one you have on server, don't forget to add the user to database. Cannot view your site.

Comment: Disable `APP_DEBUG`, change your `APP_KEY`, change your mail password, because they’re all compromised now.

Answer (score 0):

please check you database credentails in .env file then hit.

```php
php artisan config:clear
```

## note

One more thing you should blacklist your env variables from whoops output. add this to config/app.php

```php
'debug_blacklist' => [
        '_ENV' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
            'REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'MAIL_PASSWORD',
            'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
            'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
        ],
        '_SERVER' => [
            'APP_KEY',
            'DB_PASSWORD',
            'REDIS_PASSWORD',
            'MAIL_PASSWORD',
            'PUSHER_APP_KEY',
            'PUSHER_APP_SECRET',
        ],
        '_POST' => [
            'password',
        ],
    ],
```

Comment: This should be a comment in my opinion.

Comment: @Cyclonecode but there is some additional information

Comment: Ah, well it was not when I added my comment =)